# Energy of a system executing forced oscillations

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, oscillators

In L&L's textbook of Mechanics (Vol. 1 of the Course in Theoretical Physics) $\S 22$ Forced oscillations, one finds the following statement:

> \begin{equation}
> \xi = \dot{x} + i \omega x, \tag{22.9}
> \end{equation}
> \begin{equation}
> \xi = e^{i \omega t} \int\limits_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{m} F(t') e^{-i\omega t'} \mathrm{d} t' + \xi_{0}. \tag{22.10}
> \end{equation}
> Let us determine the total energy transmitted to the system during all time, assuming its initial energy to be zero. According to formula (22.10), with the lower limit of integration $-\infty$ and with $\xi(-\infty) = 0$, ... 
> The energy of the system is
> \begin{equation}
> E = \frac{1}{2} m \left(\dot{x}^{2} + \omega^{2} x^{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}m \lvert \xi\rvert^{2}.\tag{22.11}
> \end{equation}

However, at the beginning of this section, the Lagrangian is found to be
\begin{equation}
L = \frac{1}{2} m \left(\dot{x}^{2} - \omega^{2}x^{2}\right) + x F(t) \tag{22.1}
\end{equation}
where $F(t)$ is the external force driving the oscillations, so according to the definition of the energy one should have
\begin{equation}
E \equiv \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} \dot{x} - L = \frac{1}{2}m \lvert \xi\rvert^{2} - x F(t).
\end{equation}

1. Why is the term $x F(t)$ not being considered in the expression for the energy?
2. How can one simply take $\xi(-\infty) = 0$? How can one be sure that the limit exists?
3. How can one set the energy equal to zero at $t \to -\infty$? Could it not be the case that this limit is not well-defined?

Answer (score 0):

1. The Lagrangian term $xF(t)$ is an interaction term between the system and the environment. The energy of the oscillator system itself is given by eq. (22.11).

2+3. L&L assume that the oscillator is at rest at $t=-\infty$.

Comment: 1. This makes sense but then, could it be that the use of the word "system" is sloppy in this case? As it never seems to make the distinction between system as purely the oscillator and system as oscillator + external field.                                                                                                2. But if for this type of problems you always have the homogeneous solution which doesn't have a well-defined limit as $t \to -\infty$ how can you take the oscillator to be at rest at it?